# Can't see the "MIDI To" and "Midi From" options in Live 9 Suite

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.osculator.net/doc/tutorial:3) in which I should see a Midi track's output options:

[image]

but I don't even see the menu options for "MIDI From" and "MIDI To". How do I enable these?

I was previously able to see them and now I can't, so I'm not sure what changed.

This is what my screen looks like:

[image]

and I have successfully enabled the Midi Sync:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see them you need to enable the i-o button that is on the right limit of the screen, to the right of the master fader.

[image: i-o]

That's the section where you activate or hide some GUI elements. You are looking for the button above the "s r" (send, return) one. When activated, it shows in/out options for both MIDI and audio tracks.